# Cannot create folder in SD card on Android

Tags: java, android

I have this problem in my application. I want to create a folder in Emulator SD card but it didn't work and I don't know why. I tried mkdir and mkdirs.

I added WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permission to the Manifest. I tried with MediaScannerConnection and didn't work. I've searched a lot the web and tried a lot of implementations but no change. What could be the issue?

Here is my code:

```
    public void createDirIfNotExists() {


    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/cdp");
    boolean success = true;
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        success = folder.mkdirs();
    }
    if (success) {

        Log.e("Folder: ", "folder created!!");
    } else {
        Log.e("Folder Error: ", "folder cannot be created!!");
    }
}
```

My manifest look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.aboussof.myapplication" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Test">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And so I try to create the folder:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Test.this);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("A message");
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);

    // execute this when the downloader must be fired
    final DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask(Test.this);
    createDirIfNotExists();
    downloadTask.execute("http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4");

    mProgressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            downloadTask.cancel(true);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I think you don't need `.getAbsolutePath()`, so try removing it, and use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` only

Comment: thx for your answer. i tried it but the problem still exists

Comment: Try one more, remove `/` before `cdp`

Comment: the problem still exists

Comment: I mean that (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "cdp")

Comment: yes i know, i tried but but the problem still exists

Comment: I am on mobile now so cannot check much. I think you should check your AVD configuration also.

Comment: ok ill do it. thx for your help

Comment: File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/cdp/");Try using cdp/

Comment: the problem still exists

Comment: i tried it in my Phone it works!! but not in the Emulator

Comment: @user3232446: take a look at my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/cdp");
```

with

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/", "cdp");
```

Comment: the problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved your issue yet?
I use your method with a tiny change at

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "cdp");
```

And the result like the following screenshot:

[image]

[image]

My AVD configuration like the following:

[image]

Comment: Thx for your answer.  i tried the Same steps as shown but the Problem Stil exists!!  In my Android Phone it wotks but AT the Emulator Not!!  I dont know why!

Comment: Try create a new AVD with different API, for example API16, and test again. just simple method as in my answer :)

Comment: I have tested both `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/cdp")` and `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "cdp") works. So I think the problem is your AVD.

Comment: @user3232446: have you fixed your issue yet?

Comment: i changed the sdk to 16 and 19 and  no change.!

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue - file.mkdirs() returns false on android emulator API 23. And all configs was set according to BNK's answer.
Try to change API to 19 - it works for me. Looks like weird emulator/android version issue.